# How concatenate sublist in scheme?

Tags: list, scheme, concatenation, sublist

For example the list '((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (4 5 6)) 
result (1 2 3 2 3 4 4 5 6)

(
    define (concatenate  list1 list2)

```
(if (null? list1)
    list2
(
 (concatenate (cdr list1) (append (car list1) '()) )
) 
)
```

)

My idea is list1 = '((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (4 5 6)) and the result is list2 = (1 2 3 2 3 4 4 5 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only need one list parameter, given that it's already a list of lists, and there's no use for a second parameter to be used as an accumulator. Try this:

```
(define (concatenate lsts)
  (apply append lsts))

(concatenate '((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (4 5 6)))
=> '(1 2 3 2 3 4 4 5 6)
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.